# Import bulk orders in shopify development store

Tags: testing, automation, shopify, shopify-app

I have a development store in shopify and for testing purposes, I want to import bulk orders. is there a way or utility I can import bulk orders?

Comment: use Shopify- CLI to populate dummy data

Comment: Hi @Onkar, can you please guide me here how can I populate millions of dummy orders in my shopify store?